# What does this error mean in SPSS for missing values?

Tags: dataset, syntax-error, missing-data, spss

I'm doing research for my degree in epidemiology about patients at the ER. I have an SPSS dataset with 46 variables (columns) and 19228 patients (rows) defined by their patient number. To optimize the data I'm trying to use the already existing syntax another student before me has created.
One line in the syntax to show missing values is :

```
MISSING VALUES ontslagDatum ('NULL').
EXECUTE.
```

(btw ontslagDatum is Dutch for date of discharge)

If I do this I get:

```
>Error # 1137 in column 30.  Text: NULL
>A field to be read under the DATE format is invalid.  The field must contain
>day, month, and year separated by spaces, dashes, slashes, decimal points, or
>commas.  Note that American style dates (month/day/year) can be read under the
>ADATE format.  The result has been set to the system-missing value.
>Execution of this command stops.
```

Now I don't understand this for several reasons, but mostly the variable for which I'm looking for missing values is in column 7, so why column 30? The variable in column 30 is binary btw and also there is no patient number 1137. So what do the 1137 and 30 signify, I don't understand.

First I looked manually at patient on row 1137, date of discharge was not missing and was in the same format as the rest and I also looked at the variable in column 30 for this patient, but it is a correct binary value. Next I did missing value analysis (from the tab "Analyze") for variables in column 7 and column 30. Column 30 has 0 MV and column 7 has 6 MV, but it doesn't tell me where they are.
The number 1137 really puzzled me, I thought maybe every cell was numbered from the top left to right, so to figure out which cell #1137 would be I divided 1137 by 46 (number of columns) = 24.7, so the 25th row. and to figure out the column 46*24= 1104, 1137-1104= 33th column, but that variable is also binary and has a binary value.
Next I altered the syntax to:

```
MISSING VALUES ontslagDatum (' ').
EXECUTE.
```

For which I got:

```
>Error # 4811 in column 47.  Text: geboorteDatum
>String and numeric variables must be listed separately on the MISSING VALUES
>command.
>Execution of this command stops.

>Error # 4806 in column 30.  Text: NULL
>The value list on the MISSING VALUES command was not closed with a right
>parenthesis.
>Execution of this command stops.

>Error # 701 in column 30.  Text: NULL
>An undefined variable name, or a scratch or system variable was specified in a
>variable list which accepts only standard variables.  Check spelling and
>verify the existence of this variable.

>Error # 4816.  Command name: MISSING VALUES
>The variable list on the MISSING VALUES command was incorrect.

>Error # 4810 in column 34.  Text: )
>The parenthesized list of missing values was omitted.

>Error # 702 in column 34.  Text: )
>Unrecognized text was found where a variable list was expected.

>Error # 4816.  Command name: MISSING VALUES
>The variable list on the MISSING VALUES command was incorrect.

>Error # 4810 in column 1024.  Text: (End of Command)
>The parenthesized list of missing values was omitted.
```

Again, I only have 46 columns, what's with all these column numbers? What is the correct syntax for finding missing values? I'm slightly panicking as it only the third command in the first syntax file and I have like at least 5 more to go.